# Does bringing 1 cubic meter vacuum from space to Earth require more energy than the energy required for creating 1 cubic meter vacuum on Earth?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, vacuum, space

I imagine both bringing significant amount of vacuum from space to Earth and creating the same vacuum on Earth would take so much energy but I wonder which one would require more energy or would they require relatively similar amount of energy?

Let's say we have a 1 cubic meter container made out of "infinitely" strong material to contain the vacuum while bringing it from the space or while creating it on Earth for the sake of the question.

Comment: just estimate the mass of your container, than it is easy to calculate the energy to get this mass it to say 100km up, not considering the means of transport! so its really much more than just using a pump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two answers.  There's a theoretical answer that says they're the same, and a practical answer that says they are very very different.  But first, to be specific, I'd like to clarify that I'm treating "creating the same vacuum on Earth" means using pumps to generate that vacuum.

If we look at it from a theoretical perspective we see:

- In the pumping case, we can assume the container is big enough to not move.  The pump needs to push the gas out of the chamber, and it goes somewhere.  That "somewhere" eventually turns into raising the total height of the atmosphere a tiny-tiny fraction.  That is the work done.
- In the case where we bring it from space, we also displace the same amount of air, raising the height of the atmosphere a tiny-tiny fraction.

In both cases, the work done to the atmosphere is the same.  As a simple test, consider running this in reverse.  Let the air into the chamber, running past a turbine generator and see how much energy you generate.  **The amount of energy you generate will depend on the size of the vacuum chamber, and not the original source of the vacuum.**

Practically speaking, however, its enormously inefficient to get things to/from space.  To be efficient, the space solution would need to avoid wasting all of the kinetic energy that gets dumped into the atmosphere as it slows down.  Pumps were designed to do the job much more efficiently.

*On a complete aside, pumping down to a "low" vacuum is **far** more efficient than space travel.  However, if we're talking about "space," we are talking about high vacuums, or even very high vacuums (meaning extremely low pressures).  At these low pressures, **everything** out-gasses.  We even have to worry about hydrogen bleeding through the steel wall of the chamber!  As such, your cubic meter of vacuum from space is going to start to become a weaker vacuum over time.  People who work with very high vacuums are running their pumps all the time to combat these effects.  The pump will be able to keep the vacuum around longer.*

Comment: +1. "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they're different."

Comment: Hmm... You say the low vacuum and high vacuum are much different things (considering the density). The reason I asked the question is because I was thinking if it would be possible to help rockets accelerate by having vacuum containers inside the rocket, as long as the energy requirement of creating the vacuum on Earth is lower than doing the same benefit with burning fuel. Would low vacuum not help much? and how about high vacuum?

Comment: @Xtro Low and high vacuum are different beasts in terms of what is required to maintain them.  But as for propulsion, they are virtually identical.  If you have a cubic meter at 90% vacuum, you can generate 90% as much thrust as a 99.999% vacuum.  Neither one is all that effective compared to the thrust from a rocket.  The material you use to contain the vacuum is simply too heavy.  It's *much* easier to hold high pressures than low pressures because of how material strengths and the geometries work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Help me a lot. Thank you!